# How can i detect if the mouse is moving both within and out of the bounds of my window in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a small video app that i would like to give vlc-like functionality. By that, I mean having a certain element disappear and appear on mouse move or mouse not moving. I have a rough concept of how to do this but I have no ideea how i coul detect if the mouse is moving or not. I thought about using the GetPosition function but that will just give me the mouse's position and won't let me know if the cursor is moving or not. I would like to use a timer to count down 2-3 seconds after the mouse has stopped moving and then either fade out the control or just make it collapse without further ado. I can't check the value of the position variable every milisecond. Is there some other way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hook functionality so you will be *notified* when a mouse move, I use to use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) free opensource library.

How to use it:

```
using Gma.UserActivityMonitor.GlobalEventProvider;

GlobalEventProvider _globalEventProvider1 
                                 = new Gma.UserActivityMonitor.GlobalEventProvider();

this.globalEventProvider1.MouseMove += HookMouseMove;//to listen to mouse move
```

Comment: thanks for the link & lib. Will try it out and let you know, but i wouldn't want to use hooking unless as a last resort.

Comment: I will use this opensource lib. It seems to be the way 2 go.

Comment: Yes it worth it. however one note that if you want to hook only for your application not the whole system, you should change the line that use  `WH_MOUSE_LL` to `WH_MOUSE` instead and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` to `WH_KEYBOARD`, I remember that they where just a couple of lines in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the mouse.  Release the capture if the user actually clicks anywhere else.  Then you can use the standard WPF mouse move event.

```
myElement.MouseMove += (my MouseMove handler)
Mouse.Capture(myElement);
```

Comment: I don't think capturing the mouse is a necessary, PreviewMouseMove will still reach `Window` even if your mouse is over some other element, like `MediaElement` etc. Or are there some other situations that I'm not considering here?

Comment: It won't if you're not over the application at all.  I use capture because for example the user dragged a selection off the app.

Comment: Ah ok, you're right. In this case I think you could also use the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events for `Window`

Comment: You could, but without capture you can't actually track the mouse movements while off the window, which in some cases are important.

Comment: Yes, true as well. If that is a requirement mouse capture will indeed be needed

Comment: yes but what am I capturing per say if the mouse left the bounds of the actual app ? Wouldn't it make sense to capture only the window ? If not, why ?

Comment: When you capture the mouse to a control, all mouse events will go to that control until you release capture or the user switches applications. So using capture, you can always know where the user is moving the mouse. This is, for example, how your web browser can continue to scroll down and increase the selection when you drag the mouse off the bottom of the browser window.